# How to change the XML Schema Version using Java

Tags: java, xsd, xml-parsing

I have a XSD file with that has this definition:
`<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0.0">`

How can I look change this version programmatically using Java? Are there any libraries that can help me with this?

I am currently using the XMLSchema Librabry from Apache and it has get method to retrieve the version but not the set method.

```
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            XmlSchemaCollection schemaCol = new XmlSchemaCollection();
            XmlSchema schema = schemaCol.read(new StreamSource(is));
            schema.getVersion();
```

Comment: A schema is itself an XML document, so start with the [javax.xml.parsers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html) package.  If you’re familiar with XSL Transformation, there is a Java package for that as well.

Comment: Are you writing an XML schema editor? If not, why do you want to change the version of a schema?